# How to use BT or emule across 2 or more hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, bittorrent, emule

One difficulty with BT or emule is when the hard drive is full, we constantly need to move older files to a new hard drive so that we can download newer files.

We can change BT or emule's setting so that the folder for downloading points to the new hard drive, but what if emule haven't finished downloading for some files that are hard to find, and it is 92% done... in that case, we would like to keep the old setting so that when the last 8% arrives, it can go into the correct file.  (and same for BT, if we haven't finished some file or if we want to seed something later).

So is there a good way to let BT or emule point to 2 hard drives, or somehow let the new hard drive "merge" into the existing hard drive / folder?

Comment: Sounds like you need a bigger 2nd hard drive, some BT clients allow the data to automatically move to another location when it is done downloading.

Comment: does it matter whether 2nd hard drive is big or small?  ideally, if there is some way to "merge" two folders as if it is one... (two folders on different hard drives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment too: RAID - Redundant Array of [Inexpensive] Independent Disks!!!

There are two forms of RAID: hardware RAID and LVM.

With a hardware RAID, you can merge 2 HDDs in a RAID-0 configuration to sum their space, so you'll get a virtual drive that is the sum of the old drives. Pay attention that if you break 1 of them you lose both!

Second option (same reliability, same risks) is software RAID: if you don't have a RAID controller you can still merge the two disks from Computer Manager. I don't exactly remember how to, nor want to mess with my drives, but you can simply go from Control Panel\Admin tools to Computer management\Disks management and there you must convert your LBA disks to dynamic disks, then find an option to merge partitions.

I hope someone else will be able to complete my post.

Sorry for being incomplete.

Comment: yeah that sounds good. i was thinking that the OS level may have something that lets you deal with that on a transparent level... hopefully Win 7 is robust enough to handle it... and if it can add a 3rd hard drive or so forth later on too..

Comment: if not buying the expensive RAID system, then this can be a solution: http://superuser.com/questions/251649/if-using-emule-how-to-keep-current-downloading-files-while-adding-a-hard-drive