# If using eMule, how to keep current downloading files while adding a hard drive?

Tags: emule

If there are still downloading files (ones that will need extra 2 week or unknown time because they are rare files)  but need to use a new hard drive because no space is left in hard drive, then is there a way to use new hard drive while keeping existing downloads ongoing?

That's because if we change the folder in eMule from G: to H:, then all existing downloads will disappear too...

**Update:** I can move the completed files over to the new hard drive... but it is going to be a never ending task... (old hard drive gets full... move some... and repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move all folders (including having more than one tmp folder) by setting them in the directories panel of the preferences.

Comment: are you sure you can have multiple tmp folders?  (if I change c:\emule\tmp to j:\emule\tmp, then the old one will no longer be in effect, i think)

Comment: IIRC a list of tmp files is made of folders separated with "|" (pipe signs).  Click on the "+" sign to add your temp folders through the GUI, otherwise just type them one after the other.

Comment: no kidding there really can be: http://wiki.emule-web.de/index.php/Multiple_temp_directories   but what about multiple incoming directories...

Comment: Not that I know of. Sorry :-(

Comment: maybe there is no multiple incoming directories...?  but there can multiple instances of eMule running: http://wiki.emule-web.de/index.php/Multiple_instances   so they can have different incoming and tmp folders...

Comment: now i am also looking for multiple directories for uTorrent... maybe Microsoft Junction can be an answer if uTorrent doesn't support it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768

Comment: but maybe Junction cannot solve it since eMule or uTorrent will not save to a sub-folder... but now I wonder... what if for eMule or uTorrent, set the tmp folder to c:\tmp or d:\tmp and then set the complete folder to j:\completed, then they will move the completed file over, so when j: is full, add a hard drive k: and then change the completed folder to k:\completed and now it is done

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy the subfolders of the emule directory to another place. In one of them there are the files emule is downloading (If you are using the default settings). You could look the up the path in the emule settings. I think the directory is `../emule/temp` but I'm not sure. You could even simply move the one directory and change the path in the emule settings.

Comment: but... will emule be able to remember the downloaded status of those incomplete files, i wonder?  maybe the *.met files are for that purpose I wonder...   (2) what if the tmp folder is 28GB... still takes a long time to copy over...

Comment: Yeah, the .met are the ones you are looking for. Emule will remember. I have moved them around quite a lot with my emule (Insufficient disk space). It will remember the status. If the .temp folder is 28GB you should have some coffee or tee at hand *g* Take a look at this post. There they are discussing the theme, too: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/132811